# Using context with React to pass values between components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-context

Trying to use context to pass values between components:

Created a file to handle the Context: only issue I have now is that:

"Cannot call `createContext` with object literal bound to `defaultValue` because  number [1] is incompatible with  `Number` [2] in property `index`."

```
// @flow
import React, { createContext, useContext } from "react";

export type CountryIndexProviderType = {
  index: Number,
};

const CountryContext = createContext<CountryIndexProviderType>({
  index: 0,
});

type CountryContextProviderProps = {
  index: Number,
};

const CountryContextProvider = ({ index }: CountryContextProviderProps) => {
  return <CountryContext.Provider value={{ index }}></CountryContext.Provider>;
};

const useCountryIndexContext = () => useContext(CountryContext);

export { CountryContext, CountryContextProvider, useCountryIndexContext };
```

First component whereby value of index is being set:

```
import { CountryContextProvider } from "/EnteredCountriesContext";

return (
  <StyledWrappingContainer>
    <StyledProgress>{index + 2}</StyledProgress>
    <CountryContextProvider index={index}></CountryContextProvider>
  </StyledWrappingContainer>
);
```

Second component trying to consume Context:

```
import { useCountryIndexContext } from "/EnteredCountriesContext";
const { index } = useCountryIndexContext();

<StyledWrappingContainer>
   <StyledProgress>
      <StyledProgress>{index + 2}</StyledProgress>
   </StyledProgress>
</StyledWrappingContainer>
```

Have just included JSX, only other code I have relevant to my new changes around context is the import of React in the first component.

Comment: Try out https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively

Comment: If it's not about bouncing back and forth a single variable, but to share some complex state across multiple scattered components, I'd suggest to opt for some appropriate tooling, like Redux.

Comment: If your interest is rather educational, you may check out a bunch of codepens I came up with to explain React Context API: https://codepen.io/collection/XRMdwg

Comment: thanks! think i'm a lot closer to the solution now, updated my code to reflect latest version. possibly a type issue with my context file?